# Automatic test data generation

Tags: testing

I need to prepare sample test data with 5 million rows of Different employees ie;

It should contain relevant information like -

```
First Name
Last Name
Address-1
Address-2 
Zip code
st
county
country
...etc
```

Is there any tool that I can use to test it?

Comment: write small program that do that, save the result in CSV file and load it before the test. The real question is why you need it ? I would say that this may suggest problem in the test.

Comment: Why is this on SO and not on SQA forum?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the site http://www.generatedata.com/ to be good for this kind of thing - it has a bunch of different formats you can generate data in and outputs in a number of different formats that can be either read in by your code (e.g. from CSV) or easily translated into code using your favorite Unix text manipulation tools.

Answer (score 0):

Either try a webservice, like:

- http://www.generatedata.com/
- http://www.mockaroo.com/

or try one of the following utils for fake data generation:

- PHP "Faker" - https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker
- Perl's Data::Faker - [http://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Faker](http://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aFaker)
- ruby "faker" - http://faker.rubyforge.org/
- http://paulthedutchman.nl/datagenerator/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a modern PHP fake data generator, with also the ability to fake an entity.

- Fakerino: https://github.com/niklongstone/Fakerino